# How to break lines in your citation using Bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, underline

I've been having problems with LaTeX not automatically breaking the line (specifically for contents of the `title` field in entries of type `@book`) in my bibliography. I have tried everything to fix this but nothing works (including `\\` ).

Any suggestions?

[image]

Here is the code in my `reference.bib`:

```
@BOOK{Misner,      
author = "C.W. Misner and K.S. Thorne and J.A. Wheeler",      
title = "Geodesic Deviation and the Riemann Curvature Tensor",     
year = "1973",       
publisher = "W. H. Freeman",      
address = "San Francisco"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: The bibliography style controls the formatting, so you must show the `\bibliographystyle`. It should not use `\underline` but `\textit`; or if underlines are insisted on, then `\uline` (with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`, or a different underlining package).

Comment: My guess would be that your bibliography style uses `\emph`, but you (or some code you load) are loading the package `ulem` (`\usepackage{ulem}`), which turns `\emph` into underlining. Most underlines in LaTeX can't be broken across lines, so you end up with this. Either remove `\usepackage{ulem}` or if you absolutely need it, load it as `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` to stop it from changing `\emph`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for getting back to me on this. I'm using BibTex for referencing, and bibliography style {alpha}.

Comment: Oh I see the issue now... So what would be the ideal bibliography style to use?

Comment: I would bet good money that this is not actually a problem of your style. You could change the style, but I don't know if you can find one that doesn't use `\emph` at all. I suggest you try to find out whether `ulem` is the culprit (as explained in my comment above).